# Hard to find JSON.stringify bug: Don't parse inside array

Tags: arrays, json, debugging, object, stringify

I'm having a very hard time to find a `JSON.stringify` bug.

I have an object with the following structure:

```
var test_object = {
    id  : 0,
    type: 'root',

    related_dropzone_id   : 0,
    related_dropzone_order: 0,

    options : {},
    children: []
}
```

where `children` is an array of objects defined as `test_object`s like:

```
[
      12387192837: test_object_a,
      12387192838: test_object_b
]
```

of course, with different values for its properties.

When I do a `console.log(top_most_object)`, the console throws the correct object nesting with its properties but when I output a `console.log(JSON.stringify(top_most_object))` then it shows a string with the topmost `children` array as empty: `[]` aka: truncated.

The call to `JSON.stringify` doesn't throw any error so I don't know what is the issue with this.

**So the question is, how can I debug the issue here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing brackets for the objects.

```
[
      {12387192837: test_object_a},
      {12387192838: test_object_b}
]
```

[Other than that the stringify works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/GDPtX/).

Comment: Ohh boyyy!!! Yeahhhh!!!! :D Thanks for your quick answer that pointed me out for the right path!!! The issue was that I defined `children` as an `array` and not as an `object`, which was the desired behaviour in order to access the inner properties like `children[12387192837]`. It seems that at some point I changed its declaration to `children: []` from `children: {}` without notice it :( (I will need a cup of coffee or go to sleep). Thanks again!

Comment: Ah ok yeah that's the other possible way. No problem!

Comment: On the other hand, I really don't know why the console didn't thrown an error 0-0

Comment: Thats indeed strange because mine did... although I'm not absolutely sure if we had exactly the same code.

Comment: Well, I will have to go very carefull with this. Thanks again, you saved my night.